# Get eloquent model and all its relationships with one query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

#### The problem

Is there a way to get an eloquent model and **all** its relationships using only one query?

#### Example scenario:

You have both `Post` and `Comment` Eloquent models.
You add their relationships in the model class using `hasMany('Comment')` and `belongsTo('Post')` respectively.

Now this is what i've been doing to retrieve both the post AND its comments:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->comments;
return $post;
```

This returns a beautiful `json`object. The problem is, this way, i would be using two queries. That's not so great.

#### Workaround

Two alternatives come to mind:

- Using `join`statements in order to make the query i want. But Eloquent is so much more elegant.
- Leveraging the *Cache* class in order to make even fewer queries in the future (this, i will do anyway later on).

Any ideas?

Comment: Simple answer, 'No'. This is simply the way that Eloquent works

Comment: :( I was afraid that could be the case. Absolutely sure about this, Mark?

Comment: I've not come across any way of doing it, but handling relationships via a join would add an incredible amount of complexity to parsing the "flat" results returned by a join-based query back into the "shaped" model that is returned by the multiple queries.... I delved pretty deeply into the querybuilder code, and there wasn't anything that I found

Comment: Completely agree with you on the "join-based queries" issues. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: Just cache if you need to and make sure you have the proper indexes setup on your database to allow for quicker selects. Honestly a couple of queries isn't that bad anyway. You can leverage caching pretty easily: `Post::remember(10)->find($id);` will cache the result for 10 minutes.

Comment: @JasonLewis That is what I've decided to do. Thank you Jason.

Answer (score 3):

In eloquent you can do it like this

```
$post = Post::with('comments')->find($id);
return $post;
```

**Edit:**
This will not run the query with join in mysql but its just a single query in Eloquent.

Comment: How is a single query going to fetch related records without a join? I tried it, it actually runs 2 mysql queries so I don't see how it is better.